# Unable to get data from backend server after deployment

Tags: frontend, backend, render, vite, mern

I created my front end with vite + react and backend using node.js + express and mongoDB. Both my backend and frontend are hosted using Render.The bankend works fine as I'm able to see the json objects being displayed on the page.The frontend renders correctly however it is unable to fetch data from the backend.

**In console: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'N', "Not Found" is not valid JSON**

**In network: Status: 404, Type: fetch**

Everything worked fine during developmen but stops working after deployment. I suspect that my vite.config.js file is not set up correctly for deployment.

**vite.config.js**

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://gym-app-4y5d.onrender.com/",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

**Frontend**

```js
export default function Leaderboard() {
  const [onerepmaxes, setOnerepmaxes] = useState(null);

  // Fetches data from backend
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOnerepmaxes = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('/api');
      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        setOnerepmaxes(json);
      }
    };

    fetchOnerepmaxes();
  }, []);
```

Would really appreciate any type of assistance!!!

Github repo:
https://github.com/Bobsters6666/test-deployment

Frontend: https://gym-app-frontend.onrender.com/
Backend: https://gym-app-4y5d.onrender.com/api

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? If the backend does not send proper data, you need to inspect **why** this happens. As you haven't shared a single line of code, it's impossible to help you out

Comment: Hey @NicoHaase, thanks so much for your reponse! I made some edits to my original post, hope it makes sense!